# Issue with installation of spark on macbook

Tags: java, apache-spark

I installed spark on my macbook.  But, when I type "pyspark" command  in my terminal , I am getting "No Java runtime present, requesting install.". So I Installed java and typed the "pyspark" command ,but, i am still getting "No Java runtime present, requesting install.". i did try this process n number of times and but I end up getting the same thing. i am not sure what is the mistake I am doing . can anybody please help me

Comment: DId you add java to your `PATH`?

Comment: What happens when you type 'java' in the Terminal? Do you get 'command not found' or do you see the java usage instructions?

Comment: I am sorry for delayed reply. when I typed Java in my terminal, I get "No Java runtime present, requesting install."However, in my system preferences I can see Java. May i know  the issue